# How to correclty use MutationObserve in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, mutation-observers

I'm trying to observe changes to css using javascript mutationObserver in Shiny. I'm using `rhandsontable` because we can change the width of a table element in the app, and I'm trying to pick up this change iwth the mutationObserver.

The javascript doesn't seem to be working. I'm unsure why. Nothing is logged to the console, no alert message, and shiny doesn't register the variable being set by javascript.

MutationObserver code

```
jsCode <- "
    const observer = new MutationObserver(
      # this function runs when something is observed.
      function(mutations){
        console.log('activated')
        var i;
        var text;
        var widthArray = [];
        text = ''
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col').length; i++) {
          text += document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col')[i].style.width + '<br>';
          widthArray.push(document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col')[i].style.width);
        }
        alert(text)
        Shiny.setInputValue('colWidth', widthArray);
      }
    )
    const cols = document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col')
    observer.observe(cols, {
      attributes: true # observe when attributes of ul.bears change (width, height)
    })
"
```

Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jsCode))),
  rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput("dataTable")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df = data.frame(
        company = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
        bond = c(0.2, 1, 0.3, 0),
        equity = c(0.7, 0, 0.5, 1),
        cash = c(0.1, 0, 0.2, 0),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  output$dataTable <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(df, manualColumnResize = TRUE, manualRowResize = TRUE)
    })
  observeEvent(input$colWidth, {
    print(input$colWidth)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
jsCode <- "
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    const observer = new MutationObserver(
      function(mutations){
        console.log('activated')
        var i;
        var text;
        var widthArray = [];
        text = ''
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col').length; i++) {
          text += document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col')[i].style.width + '<br>';
          widthArray.push(document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('col')[i].style.width);
        }
        alert(text)
        Shiny.setInputValue('colWidth', widthArray);
      }
    )
    const cols = document.getElementsByClassName('htCore')[0].getElementsByTagName('colgroup')[0]
    observer.observe(cols, {
      attributes: true, subtree: true 
    });
  }, 500);
});
"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions, why do we need to use ```setTimeout```? Also, why do we need ```$(document).on("shiny:connected", ...```? Instead of this, would it also work if I use ```runjs(jsCode)``` on serverside to execute the observer code once?

Comment: @Frank We need that to delay, otherwise the elements are not found.

Comment: @Frank See <https://stackoverflow.com/q/65636472/1100107> for a better way.

Comment: @Frank If you prefer the solution with the mutation observer, it would be better to put the JS code in the `onRender` function, instead of using a delay.