# How to use the 'afterColumnResize' event with 'rhandsontable'?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

The JavaScript library **Handsontable** has an event [afterColumnResize](https://handsontable.com/docs/8.2.0/Hooks.html#event:afterColumnResize), triggered when a column is manually resized. How to use it with the 'rhandsontable' package in Shiny?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmlwidgets)

jsCode <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  Handsontable.hooks.add('afterColumnResize', function(index, size){",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('newsize', {index: index+1, size: size});",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("dataTable"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("sizeinfo")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df = data.frame(
    company = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    bond    = c(0.2, 1, 0.3, 0),
    equity  = c(0.7, 0, 0.5, 1),
    cash    = c(0.1, 0, 0.2, 0),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  output$dataTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(df, manualColumnResize = TRUE, manualRowResize = TRUE) %>% 
      onRender(jsCode)
  })
  output$sizeinfo <- renderPrint({
    req(input$newsize)
    sprintf(
      "Column %d has new size %dpx.", 
      input$newsize$index, input$newsize$size
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## Edit: case of multiple tables

If you have multiple handsontables, and you want to add the hook to only one of them, add the hot instance after the callback:

```r
jsCode <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  var hot = this.hot;",
  "  Handsontable.hooks.add('afterColumnResize', function(index, size){",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('newsize', {index: index+1, size: size});",
  "  }, hot);",
  "}"
)
```

Comment: This solution is great but what if you have two ```rhandsontables``` in 1 page? Then how would you differentiate the altered column between the two tables?

Comment: @Frank I think this is not possible with `rhandsontable`. This would be possible if the tables were initiated with jQuery, but this is not the way used by the author of the package.

Comment: @Frank Hmm... after thinking there may be a solution: one could send the table id to the Shiny server in addition, when a column is resized. But there's no way to control the  `afterColumnResize` event for only one table if there are other ones.

Comment: I was thinking if there is some js code I can run every time a table is clicked to query the column sizes ```observeEvent(input$dataTable, {runjs( <code>)```? 
But I think the above method will work if multiple ```rhandsontables``` are on different tabs, if I just check which tab is opened before running code on server.

Comment: @Frank I was wrong when I said *"there's no way to control the afterColumnResize event for only one table if there are other ones"*. See my edit.